# Fortigate 300C : Web-Filter not working

Tags: firewall, fortigate

I have fortigate 300C firewall.

I have create the web-filter policy for one department, I have added only websites which are allowed (around 1200 websites) rest all I want to block.

But somehow filter is not working, proxy websites and other websites like fantacycricket, viu.com, etc are still opening.

On last line of filter I have added * wildcard -> block. Still it is not working.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ssl inspection. If you don't configure SSL inspection the fortigate won't block HTTPS web pages

Comment: ok thx, ill check.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Configure webfilterring  inbound and outbound deny  policy in firewall . And bottom configure allow policy .  And configure explicitly  deny policy .

**Option 2**

Configure object for webfilterring

URL should configure in  object and enable deny option and configure policy in fortigate firewalls

Any traffic coming towards firewall hits this security policy . Traffic with this URL matches policy and deny traffic remaining traffic will allow .